# PHP Echo Not Showing

Tags: php, variables, echo

Alright I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here but I cannot for the life of get these PHP variables to display inline!

EDIT: This is what the code looks like now, stil not working.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);
//declare variables
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$company = 'Test company';
$dateraw = $date;

$confirmText = "Thank you " . $name . " for booking your appointment with us. We look forward to seeing you at " .$time . " on " . $dateraw . ". You will receive a confirmation email shortly.";

//strip of invalid chars
$date = str_replace( '/' , '.' , $date);

//fopen
$pathToMe = dirname(__FILE__);
$fileName = $pathToMe . "/days/" . $date . ".txt";
$fileHandle = fopen($fileName, 'w') or die("Failure.");
fwrite($fileHandle, $name . "\n" . $email . "\n" . $phone . "\n" . $date . "\n" . $time . "\n" . $comments . "\n" . "\n" ); 
fclose($fileHandle);

//email to company
$to = 'peter@pkazz.com';
$subject = 'Apointment scheduled online';
$body = "An apointment was just scheduled online.\n" . $name . "\n" . $email . "\n" . $phone . "\n" . $date . "\n" . $time . "\n" . $comments . "\n" . "\n" . "Please follow up to confirm.";
if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
    $companyConfirm = 'yes';
} else {
    $companyConfirm = 'no';
}

//client confirm
$to = $email;
$subject = 'Confirming your appointment';
$body = "Hello " . $name . "," . "\n" . "\n"  . "You recently booked an appointment with " . $company . " on " . $date . " at " . $time . ".\n" . "\n" . "We will follow up soon to confirm.";
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body)) {
    $confirm = 'yes';
} else {
    $confirm = 'no';
}

print_r($_POST);


?>



<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="jqt">

            <div id="home" class="current">
                <div class="toolbar">
                    <h1>Scheduler</h1>
                </div>
                    <ul class="edit rounded">
                       <li><?php echo $confirmText; ?></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting the HTML output without the PHP variables being echo'd? Or are you getting nothing at all? Are you POSTing to the page (and no redirects between the POST and this output?)

Comment: I think you're being too trusting of your data input. `$email = $_POST['email']` followed by `$to = $email` for example. (SMTP injection.)

Comment: Thanks @ian but this is purely proof of concept, not going to be public. @HorusKol the variables are being POSTed fine (the email confirmations are sending and the text files are being written fine).

Comment: There is an issue with the variables. For some reason they work in the email and file creation parts of the php, but when I make the string with the message (`$confirmText = "Thank you " . $name . " for booking your appointment with us. We look forward to seeing you at " .$time . " on " . $dateraw . ". You will receive a confirmation email shortly.";`) the variables fail to appear in the HTML, only the text portions.

Comment: Hmm. Have you got a misplaced > in your Javascript and styling? I'd start with a `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at top to check for any silliness. Then check the HTML source after if no apparent errors.

Comment: @Ian adding `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` did not show any errors. Looking at the source from my broswer shows the exact same thing: string with no variables. Emails are still going through just fine. I even moved the creation of the string to just after the declaration of the `$_POST` variables to see if that changed anything. No effect.

Comment: Remove `session_start();` for now, and do `print_r($_POST);` - anything?

Comment: @Ian SO weird. I'm getting `Undefined index:  date in submit.php on line 8` for every variable now, even though they are defined from the post a line before. Full script here: http://pastebin.com/iJJYgT6P. Doesn't make sense because 20 lines later the emails are sending fine and using the variables (confirmed this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a body sent before header bug (try turning on your error messges). It happens here:
`<?php` (line 0)

and

```
   $confirm = 'no';
}
?>

<?php session_start(); ?>
```

To solve this, make sure you have **only** one `<?php` before the `session_start`, that it has no spaces before that, and you do not save the page with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: Removed the `session_start` all together because I had no `$_SESSION` variables that would have required it to see if it would help. No effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use rtrim on each of the variables before echoing them. Second suggestion is why not generate the complete string in php script as well

```
$display_message = "Thank you".$name."for booking your appointment with us. We look forward to seeing you at".$time."on".$dateraw."You will receive a confirmation email shortly";
```

Then simply  anywhere you like inside the html portion.

Hope this helps

Comment: Creating the message in the PHP had an odd effect. The string was created without any variables. See above.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this style of inline echo instead:

`<?php=$name;?>`

Or try moving `session_start()` up to the very top of your code.